# AutoComplete for HTML tags in Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, code-completion

Coming from the VisualStudio world to Eclipse! I have a question:

I have created a *File->New->Project->General Project* and added a `.htm` file to it and went to its text editor mode. But it does not have intellisence for HTML tags when I type them. Then I installed Aptana plug-in and tought it will bring auto-complete for my tags, but it did not change anything. So we have to type everything? No Intellisense for HTML in Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best HTML editor for Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse goto

```
Window->Preferences->HTML Files -> Editor ->Content Assist
```

and paste this whole line instead of **<=** in Promt when these characters are inserted... !

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._<=
```

then apply and close & Enjoy Coding !

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Web Tools Platform (WTP)](http://eclipse.org/webtools/), that should give you auto completion.

Comment: Or get "Eclipse for Java EE" or "Eclipse for JavaScript" instead of "Eclipse for Java" or "Eclipse Classic" respectively.

Comment: @BalusC: correct, thanks for the addition. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse

Comment: I recently installed "Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Developers" but it does not have the feature of auto-completing the html tag. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac on the top of your screen click the **Eclipse** button Preferences -> HTML Files -> Content Assist and then in the "Prompt when these characters are inserted" area enter:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._<=

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30195761)

Answer (score 0):

in latest eclipse (2023) it has been changed -> Windows>Preferences>Web>HTML files>editor>content Assistant.

Then you can change some settings here like promt when you insert something and speed.